# are you able to still us a google account after frp

Tags: factory-reset

if I bypasss the frp can I still use a google account or do I have to use the previously synced one?

Comment: Guess I am confused... If you have your Google account credentials, why are you trying to bypass FRP?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use any Google account after the bypass was successful. 
Some bypass methods, especially the one with Google account manager, require you put your own account which will allow you to unlock the FRP.